# Why does David Foster Wallace say to David Lispky, "I got 20 years to get you back."

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-end-of-the-tour

In the movie [*The End of the Tour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_the_Tour) a scene shows David Foster Wallace and David Lipsky walk into a radio station and are greeted by a girl.

> Girl from the radio station: Right this way. We record digitally. I hope that's okay.
>
> David Foster Wallace: So just yes or no answers?
>
> David Lipsky: That's very funny.
>
> Wallace to Lipsky: Hey.
>
> Lipsky: What?
>
> Wallace: Hey. You do a really mean job with this,
>
> Lipsky: Yeah?
>
> Wallace: I got, like, 20 years to get you back. You remember that.
>
> Lipsky: You're gonna be fine.

This scene ends here. What does Wallace mean? He makes a joke to the girl and then turns to his companion Lipsky and seemingly says a non sequitur. I don't see how it follows from the previous line or even makes sense. Something like "If you botch this you are going to be put away"? But Wallace is the one doing the radio interview and Lipsky is only tagging along.